# Regular Expression for Current Date and Time

Tags: java, regex, date

I have a Date object (Thu Jul 16 15:54:56 IST 2015).

```
Date date = new Date();

if(vea.isDateValid("Thu Jul 16 15:04:45 IST 2015","regex")){
    System.out.println("Given Date" + " is a valid date format.");  
} else {  
    System.out.println("Given Date" + " is an invalid date format.");  
}
```

Please give suggestion for 
 "date"
 regular Expression without converting to any form.

Comment: What is it that you want to do with the date?

Comment: @anubhava I need to Compare current date and time with Regular Expression.If it matches returns True, else false.

Comment: Why not compare `Date`s directly? Or event `String#equals`?  What are you trying to compare?

Comment: @MadProgrammer I don't need any methods to change date format. just i need "regex" for Current date and time from Date(java.util.Date).

Comment: There A LOT of valid formats for a date (this just 16/07/2015 and Wednesday, 07.16.2015 ). If you don't know the general structure of the String, you can't possibly write a (manageable) single regexp for all the cases

Comment: Once you have the defined format, you can instantiate a SimpleDateFormat case with the approriate String, and try to match. If it fails, it's not valid. If it succeeds, it is.

Comment: @DiegoMartinoia but those are not valid formats for my requirement.

Comment: Regular Expression will only tell if the "format" is correct, not if the date is valid, which is why people are scratching their heads over your question. Something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20231539/java-check-the-date-format-of-current-string-is-according-to-required-format-or/20232680#20232680) will valid a `String` date based on a series of predefined formats, but it will do two things, valid the format AS well as validate the date...

Comment: @MadProgrammer my question is not about current date. just need format like that only.

Comment: So, would something like `Abc Efg 99 99:99:99 HIJ 9999` be a valid value for your format?  Cause that's all regular expression will tell, not if the actual value is valid Date value...just saying ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer exactly.

Comment: ^((31(?! (FEB|APR|JUN|SEP|NOV)))|((30|29)(?! FEB))|(29(?= FEB (((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|((16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00)))))|(0?[1-9])|1\d|2[0-8])-(JAN|FEB|MAR|MAY|APR|JUL|JUN|AUG|OCT|SEP|NOV|DEC)-((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)\d{2})$

Comment: I found above format but it's not meet my requirement

Comment: What is the format you want to parse? Post an example string please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the Regex you need :

```
[A-Z][a-z]{2}\\s[A-Z][a-z]{2}\\s[0-9]{2}\\s[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\\s[A-Z]{3}\\s[0-9]{4}
```

And in your Java code it would be like this:

```
Date dt=new Date();
String dateString = dt.toString();

System.out.println(dateString.matches("[A-Z][a-z]{2}\\s[A-Z][a-z]{2}\\s[0-9]{2}\\s[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\\s[A-Z]{3}\\s[0-9]{4}"));
```

Here's the **[Working DEMO](https://ideone.com/oZgNW2)**.

Comment: Thank you work like charm!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should also work, i think it is more convenient to read the format this way:

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss z YYYY);

    try {
        Date date = sdf.parse(dateToValidate);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
```