# SQLite avoid crashes when data is inputted wrong

Tags: android, sqlite

I am new to android programming and have just managed to build a working sqlite database.

However when data is entered incorrectly, such as into the "Expiry date" section which requires the user to input in the format of YYYY/MM/DD, the program will crash if inputted wrong. Is there a way to reject the information being added to the database avoiding the crash?

Below is the code for setting up the database and inputting into the respective columns

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME + " (" + COL_1 + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + COL_2 + " TEXT," + COL_3 + " DATE," + COL_4 + " DATE" + ")");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);

    onCreate(db);
}

public boolean insertData(String Name, String Datereceived, String Expirydate) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL_2, Name);
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    contentValues.put(COL_3, dateFormat.format(new Date(Datereceived)));
    contentValues.put(COL_3, Datereceived);
    contentValues.put(COL_4, dateFormat.format(new Date(Expirydate)));
    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
    if (result == -1)
        return false;
    else
        return true;

}
```

And here is the code for the updating the database

```
 public void UpdateData() {
    btnviewUpdate.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    boolean isUpdate = myDb.updateData(editTextId.getText().toString(), editname.getText().toString(),
                            editdate.getText().toString(), editexpiry.getText().toString());
                    if (isUpdate == true)
                        Toast.makeText(DatabaseUpdater.this, "Data updated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    else
                        Toast.makeText(DatabaseUpdater.this, "Data not updated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
    );
}
```

Comment: please share ur logs

Comment: Simply check if the inputted date is valid. Reject the insertion (with an alert to the user) if it's not.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
public boolean insertData(String Name, String Datereceived, String Expirydate) {
   try {
       SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
       ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
       contentValues.put(COL_2, Name);
       SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
       contentValues.put(COL_3, dateFormat.format(new Date(Datereceived)));
       contentValues.put(COL_3, Datereceived);
       contentValues.put(COL_4, dateFormat.format(new Date(Expirydate)));
       long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
       if (result == -1)
           return false;
       else
           return true;
   } catch(Exception x) {
      return false;
   }
```

Not very good but you can start with that.

Answer (score 1):

do one thing before putting the value in database check is it a valid date or not ,you can insert the data if its valid or insert some dummy value.use the below code to check its valid date or not

```
   public static boolean isValidFormat(String format, String value) {
    Date date = null;
    try {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
        date = sdf.parse(value);
        if (!value.equals(sdf.format(date))) {
            date = null;
        }
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return date != null;
}
```

More date validity check try this link -- [Java: Check the date format of current string is according to required format or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20231539/java-check-the-date-format-of-current-string-is-according-to-required-format-or)