# Check the date format of string if it's according to required format or not

Tags: swift, swift3, nsdateformatter

I have the same question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20231539/java-check-the-date-format-of-current-string-is-according-to-required-format-or) in Java,
is it possible in swift?

```
func stringToDate(str: String) -> Date{

    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"

    //check validation of str 

    return date
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Just same like `Java`, check if it can parse properly

```
let dateFormatterGet = DateFormatter()
dateFormatterGet.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"
let someDate = "string date"

if dateFormatterGet.date(from: someDate) != nil {
    // valid format
} else {
    // invalid format
}
```

Comment: someDate isn't an optional, so you don't need to force unwrap

Comment: what if I enter date string as "2018-bcjbxhc-12 12:30:14"

Answer (score 9):

For Swift 4 the syntax have changed a bit:

```
 func isValidDate(dateString: String) -> Bool {
    let dateFormatterGet = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatterGet.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"
    if let _ = dateFormatterGet.date(from: dateString) {
        //date parsing succeeded, if you need to do additional logic, replace _ with some variable name i.e date
        return true
    } else {
        // Invalid date
        return false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in swift3 :

```
func stringToDate(str: String) -> Date{

    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"

    guard let date = dateFormatter.date(from: str){
        return Date()
    }

    return date

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5

```
let dateFormatterGet = DateFormatter()
dateFormatterGet.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"
let someDate = "string date"

if dateFormatterGet.date(from: someDate!) != nil {

} else {
    // invalid format
}
```