# Android date string parsing illegal dates - Kotlin

Tags: android, date, kotlin

I am trying to set up a piece of code that willonly return true with legal dates. So with mask "MM/dd/yy" 02/02/62 would be legal but 66/66/66 would not.(However in that last case the date is being translated as *Mon Aug 05 00:00:00 EST 71*.

Here is the code:

```
fun legalDoB(): Boolean {
    val dobString = dobTextId.text.toString()
    val df = SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy")
    try {
        val date:Date = df.parse(dobString)
        Log.d(DEBUG,"Legal Date $date")
        return true
    } catch (e: ParseException){
        Log.d(DEBUG,"NOT Legal Date")
        return false
    }
    return false
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer comes from jAnA on the SO question: ( [Java: Check the date format of current string is according to required format or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20231539/java-check-the-date-format-of-current-string-is-according-to-required-format-or) )

that is to use: .setLenient(false).

In Kotlin that means my original code should be:

```
fun legalDoB(): Boolean {
    val dobString = dobTextId.text.toString()
    val df = SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy")
    df.isLenient = false
    try {
        val date:Date = df.parse(dobString)
        Log.d(DEBUG,"Legal Date $date")
        return true
    } catch (e: ParseException){
        Log.d(DEBUG,"NOT Legal Date")
        return false
    }
    return false
}
```